# Replaceing column content with image doesnt work. It only replaces last

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, setinterval, appendchild

[LOOK at the image PLEASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWHy0.png)
There is a table that is refreshing every second with AJAX. 2nd column of table has 0 or 1 inside. I want to replace 0 with one image and  1 with another image. Currently I am looping through all the rows but only last row of one kindof image is filled in. All row shoul have a picture in them. What am I doing wrong?

```
  var warningImg =  document.createElement("IMG");
                    warningImg.src = "icone/ic_warning.png";

                var okImg = document.createElement("IMG");
                    okImg.src = "icone/ic_done.png";      

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            setInterval(function() {
                $.get("IOdoc.htm", function(result){
                    var stringArray = result.trim().split(",");

                    $('#safety tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').text(stringArray[0]);
                    $('#safety tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').text(stringArray[1]);
                    $('#safety tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)').text(stringArray[2]);

                    var safetyEls = document.querySelectorAll("#safety tr td:nth-child(2)");

                    for(var i=0; i < safetyEls.length ; i++){
                        if (safetyEls[i].innerHTML.trim() == "1")
                        {
                            safetyEls[i].appendChild(okImg);
                        }
                        else{
                            safetyEls[i].appendChild(warningImg);} 
                    }
            });
        },1000);
    });
```

I tried something that proves that for loop is working. I replaced appendChild with textContent just wrote some text. 
safetyEls[i].textContent = "Warning"

This worked. [Working table just with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFyzg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call the `appendChild`, you **move** the image you have created.

Try cloning it to create new image for each row:

```
                   if (safetyEls[i].innerHTML.trim() == "1")
                    {
                        safetyEls[i].appendChild(okImg.cloneNode(true));
                    }
                    else{
                        safetyEls[i].appendChild(warningImg.cloneNode(true));} 
                }
```

For more details see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp